# Magento : How to Get product from cart and add it again

Tags: php, magento, product, cart

I want to get all the product from cart in a array. and i want to remove all the products from cart. after that i want to add the same products with same quantity and options which are selected by customer again in the cart based on some conditions. i did the following.

1) Save all the products in a array which are available in cart. Using following code.

```
$quote = $this->getQuote();

$i=0;

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $bufferItems[$i] = $item;
        $i++;
}
```

2) Remove all the products from cart using following code.

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $quote->getItemsCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
}
```

Up to this everything is working fine.

Now i don't know how to add the product back to the cart... can any one help me.

i did the following which is not working.

```
1) $quote->addProduct($bufferItems[1]);
2) $quote->addItem($bufferItems[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$cartItems = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems();

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');

$cart->init();

 foreach($cartItems as $item) {
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
   $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $item->getQty()));
 }

 $cart->save();
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: Wow that was working fine Thanks :) . but only one problem :( . order total is same for all the orders. and the product price is "0.00" for all the order products. can you help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code within your code

```html
$params = array(
    'product' => 164,
    'qty' => 2,
);
 
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
 
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->load(164);
 
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
 
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
 
$message = $this->__('Custom message: %s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
```